# Using which condition vs using simple condition

Tags: r, object, vector

Which way is the best way to filter an object, using `which` or a simple condition?

`x[-which(x > 0)]` is the same of `x[x <= 0]`? Is there any case when the output is not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases when the `-which` can give incorrect results

```
> x <- 1:5
> x[-which(x > 5)]
integer(0)
> x[x <=5]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

A bug free approach is negation (`!`)

```
> x[!x > 5]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```